# Orientation in UITabBarController + UIViewController

Tags: iphone

Anyone please answer for my requirement

Im using my application in this order,

first page = UIViewController,
secondpage = UITabBarController with 4 tabs,

1. I need landscape on the orientation on the second tabpage(UIViewController) ? not working..

Note : When using UITabBarController its working perfect but when I add the UIViewController for my first page, the orientation not working...?

anyone who knows the solution plz answer

Answer (score 0):

finally orientation works fine in UITabBarController while adding a separate UIViewController